# Problems with jQuery event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
  for(i=0; i<allPoints[0].length; i++) {
   var pointX = controlPoint[i].x;
   var pointY = controlPoint[i].y;
   var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
   var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
   if(pointX + 5 > mouseX && pointX - 5 < mouseX && pointY + 5 > mouseY && pointY - 5 < mouseY) {
    var testest = i;
    $(this).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    //'i' is undefined here
    //'testest' is defined
     controlPoint[testest].x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
     controlPoint[testest].y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    });
   }
  }
 }).mouseup(function(e){
  $(this).unbind('mousemove');
 });
```

For some reason when I try to use the variable 'i' from the for loop inside of my `mousemove` function it is undefined. If I assign it to another variable before that works for some reason, but I don't want to do that because it seems unnecessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't know for sure, but I believe it's, because your `i` variable is *global*. Always declare a variable that should not be `global` with a `var` keyword. For example,

```
for(var i=0; i<allPoints[0].length; i++) {
```

I think your application modifies the variable `i` somewhere else and that is the reason why assigning it to another variable seems to solve your problem. The real solution here is to use a *local* variable with a `var` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know that. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem, I changed 'i=0' to 'var i=0' like you said but 'i' is still undefined. Also, 'i' isn't used in the rest of my script other than for function parameters, which are always local, as far as I know.

Comment: Are you sure? Try changing all `i`'s to `abc`'s.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that i is undefined is very bizarre. The only way this can happen is if it's being set to undefined somewhere else in your code.  If the global variable i is never used anywhere else, then the value of i will always be equivalent to allPoints[0].length inside your 'mousemove' callback because you're creating a closure around the i variable, which will be set to allPoints[0].length by the end of the mousedown callback.  Also, be aware that testest will be hoisted to the top of the mousedown callback, so the value of testest inside the mousemove callback will always be the last value that was set inside the mousemove callback.